# hover state not working on visited links

Tags: hyperlink, hover

Can someone tell me why does the hover state stops working once i visit a link?

http://jsfiddle.net/trajaneu/ZBzV9/

Links on the footer belonging to class "contactos" work well. But those on the class "texto" are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I've found the problem here:

```
.contactos a:link,.texto div a:visited,.texto div a .yshortcuts {
```

I've just replaced "texto div" for "contactos". Copy-paste sometimes has these effects :)